# Memoir and positioning table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I am using solution from [Fixed top margin on normal text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616636/fixed-top-margin-on-normal-text) but after adding ToC it behaves strange.

First problem is that the `\contentsname` of ToC has different style than other chapters. What can I do to have same style?

Second problem is that the ToC page is shifted down.

```
\documentclass[oneside, 11pt]{memoir}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[top=5cm,bottom=3cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vbox to 0pt{%
\vss
\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@
}%
\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\vbox to 0pt{%
\parindent \z@ \raggedright
\normalfont
\Large \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@
}%
\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum[1-9]

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The ToC, LoF and LoT titles are set like a `\chapter*` The following  modification of your MWE just adjusts the location and size of the ToC title (read section **9.2.1 Changing the titles** in the manual).

```
% titleoftocprob.tex  SE 619689

\documentclass[oneside, 11pt]{memoir}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[top=5cm,bottom=3cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vbox to 0pt{%
\vss
\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@
}%
\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\vbox to 0pt{%
\parindent \z@ \raggedright
\normalfont
\Large \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@
}%
\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum[1-9]

\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%% change the loaction and size of the ToCtitle
\renewcommand{\tocheadstart}{\vspace*{-60pt}}
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}{\Large\bfseries}
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Alternatively you could redefine how a `\chapter*` is set to match how you redefined the `\chapter` settings.

Comment: Thank you Peter. It looks very good. It solves the ToC title style and position. There is one small think. The vertical space between ToC title and ToC 'content' is bigger than space under chapter. Is possible to customize this space somehow?

Comment: @kolisko Yes, Read the manual.