# Adjust page margins: Text body always below chapter area

Tags: margins, koma-script, geometry

How can the page margins be adjusted such that chapter headline (always at the top of a page) is above the main text body. As a consequence, the chapter space is left blank on pages without chapter headings.

[image: min. example]

Currently, I am using koma script (scrbook) and ideally would like to make the adjustments to this class, but don't need necessarily stick to that.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{scrbook} 
            
\title{Book Title}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\mainmatter

\KOMAoptions{open=left}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/616636/219947) for the standard  `book` class.

Comment: Thanks. At least one answer seems to work for koma script, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at all sure what you want, but perhaps the `memoir` class provides for you.

```
% chaptitleprob.tex  SE 628145

\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{memoir}

\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-100pt} % space above chapter title
            
\title{Book Title}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\mainmatter

%\KOMAoptions{open=left}
\openleft  % can be a memoir class option
\chapter{Chapter One}
\Blindtext

\Blindtext

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

The class provides three lengths: `\beforechapskip` vertical space before the title; `\midchapskip` space between number and title text; `\afterchapterskip` space between the title and body text. Read the manual for more details.

**EDIT**

It seems that I did not correctly understand the question. I now take it that the general textblock should be the same on all pages with chapter titles typeset above the general textblock (e.g, put up into the header area).

```
% chaptitleprob2.tex  SE 628145

\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{memoir}

%%%%% some trial settings to lift and reduce chapter title's space
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-100pt} % space above chapter title
%\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-150pt} % space above chapter title
%\setlength{\midchapskip}{25pt} % space between number and title
\setlength{\midchapskip}{20pt} % space between number and title
\setlength{\midchapskip}{15pt} % space between number and title
%\setlength{\afterchapskip}{25pt} % space below chapter title
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{5pt} % space below chapter title
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{10pt} % space below chapter title
            
\title{Book Title}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\mainmatter

%\KOMAoptions{open=left}
\openleft  % can be a memoir class option
\chapter{Chapter One}
\Blindtext

\Blindtext

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

I really don't know how you want your document to look. You may wish to change the size of the textblock to make the first and second chapter pages look cohesive, which would probably mean with fiddling with the `\...chapskip` lengths. Good luck with your book design.

Comment: Thanks. It does not help me with my issue but it might be a solution for others. I am compiling a book with one or two paged chapters (e.g. recipies, poems, whatever) and the chapter heading is always rather small. On two paged chapters, I don't want the text to be in the chapter heading area.

Comment: @kromuchi I have added a second answer which is the best I can do for my understanding of your problem.

Comment: thank you for this memoir solution. I found a solution for scrbook in the [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/616636/219947](question) mentioned by Imran, but the memoir approach seems to be more elegant.